# Cython compatible with Python 2.6.6

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

Currently I develop a small `Python` project and use `Cython` to build it to `.so` file.

When I run the `.so` file in `Centos server with Python 2.6.6`, I got the message

> ImportError: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

Does this problem come from Cython version? Which version of Cython that can work with Python 2.6.6?

Comment: I'm curious, are you limited to only using Python 2.6? It was made in 2008.

Comment: @DanielScott: Yes, the customer server install CentOS 6.x that the basic Python version is 2.6.6. It's difficult to request upgrade to version 2.7

Comment: There may be other issues (I don't know what Cython's backwards compatibility is like) but this is simply telling you that you've linked your module to Python 2.7. Try linking it to Python 2.6 instead - the easiest way would be to use Python 2.6 to run setup.py